# сохранение docx при использование классa ZipArchive

Tags: php

для создания или изменение во вновь созданых  docx документах использую класс ZipArchive
создаю или открываю его таким образом

```
if ( $this->open( $filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
        die("Unable to open <$filename>\n");
      }
```

но после окончания работы надо что бы как минимум браузер начинал загрузку созданого файла (а в идиале что бы он автоматически сохранялся на рабочий стол пользователя в определеную папку).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтоб браузер начал загрузку файла, ему надо об этом сказать. Для этого сервер должен отдать примерно такие заголовки

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```